Deserializar XML mal formado
Tengo un XML que tiene mal formato. Ese formato no lo puedo cambiar, ya que hay más servicios que dependen y esperan el XML tal cual.
Pero estoy haciendo una librería nueva que lee de esos mismos XML, pero para auto deserializarlos necesita los datos de una manera más correcta.
El XML es asi:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<inicio>
 <archivo>
   <comun>
     <idArchivo>9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6</idArchivo>
     <edicion>PG</edicion>
     <firma></firma>
     <descripcion></descripcion>
     <palabras></palabras>
     <extension>JPG</extension>
     <urlIcono>/ICONOS/9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6.JPG</urlIcono>
     <urlImagen>/IMAGENES/9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6.JPG</urlImagen>
     <urlportada>/IMGPORTADA/9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6.JPG</urlportada>
     <urlportadadoble>/IMGPORTADADOBLE/9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6.JPG</urlportadadoble>
     <urlGrande>/IMG/9A904D97-DD29-F1D7-F1256142C1B054F6.JPG</urlGrande>
     <nombreOriginal><![CDATA[pack dia del padre.jpg]]></nombreOriginal>
     <fechaAlta>2023-04-27 14:20:04.0</fechaAlta>
     <fechaModificacion>2023-04-27 14:20:04.0</fechaModificacion>
     <fechaPublicacion>2023-04-27</fechaPublicacion>
     <idiomaPorDefecto>es</idiomaPorDefecto>
     <estado></estado>
     <pesoArchivoOriginal> Mb</pesoArchivoOriginal>
   </comun>
   <pieFoto>
     <es><![CDATA[pack dia del padre.jpg]]></es>
   </pieFoto>
   <descripcion>
     <es></es>
   </descripcion>
   <palabras>
     <es></es>
   </palabras>
 </archivo>
</inicio>

Y la clase donde yo quiero meterlo tiene esta forma:
public class Archivo : IClaseBasePersefone
{
    private string Directorio { get => "ARCHIVOS"; }

    private string idField;

    private string edicionField;

    private string firmaField;

    private string extensionField;

    private string urlIconoField;

    private string urlImagenField;

    private string urlPortadaField;

    private string urlPortadaDobleField;

    private string urlGrandeField;

    private string nombreOriginalField;

    private DateTime fechaAltaField;

    private DateTime fechaModificacionField;

    private DateTime fechaPublicacionField;

    private string idiomaPorDefectoField;

    private string estadoField;

    private string pesoArchivoOriginalField;

    private List<IdiomaValor> listaPieFotoField;

    private List<IdiomaValor> listaDescripcionField;

    private List<IdiomaValor> listaPalabrasField;

    // propiedas publicas y metodos extra
}

Como se ve, no puedo deserializarlo directamente, ya que el deserializador espera una clase inicio.
También está el problema de que en la clase no quiero nada de comun. Quiero una clase archivo con las propiedades ahí, nada de subclases.
¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo? Yo he pensado en coger el stream del XML y modificarlo y luego ya intentar la serialización, pero si se puede con atributos estaría genial.

Por que dices que tiene mal formato? A mi me valida correctamente el ejemplo que proporcionas

Usa transformaciones.

@pikoh el formato es correcto. pero no debería haber un elemento inicio ni el elemento común, aparte de que las listas no deberían de tener elementos con el nombre del idioma, sino con el nombre más descriptivo. Lo que yo quiero es hacer un XML con un determinado formato a partir de otro

Gracias @Sal. Estoy usando transformaciones (que no las conocía), pero me gustaria algo con atributos

Agrega a tu pregunta un ejemplo del resultado esperado y del xslt.

No veo para que @Sal. Con transformaciones lo tengo funcionando. La pregunta original preguntaba por las anotaciones  [] encima de las clases
